# Download Windows 7 and use HP's product key?

Tags: windows-7, windows, license-key

My Hewlett Packard computer came preinstalled with Windows 7 Home Premium x64. It did not come with a Windows 7 install DVD.

I need to reinstall it because its full of viruses and whatnot.

Can I download the Windows 7 .iso file from [digitalriver](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso) and use the product key that came in the preinstalled Windows 7 ?

Comment: When you try it and find out, please post an Answer here

Comment: @Sparr It worked using the product key from the sticker rather than the one from the preinstalled Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [should](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/can-an-oem-licence-key-be-used-to-activate-a/495b4da1-c1b7-4d93-82a9-8c8601bbaf32) work if you have the full license key for your Windows license. If you don't have the license key (or can't read it because it's worn off), you're stuck; the remaining information is insufficient to get back your product key. Basically you should write down your product key and store it in a safe place **right now** because, being on the bottom of your unit, the product key may suffer damage and then you can't reinstall Windows any more.

Comment: It should work fine but ensure you download the exact same version of the install CD as the product key was intended for. If it was intended for Win7 SP1, then a Win7 CD will not work. Likewise the opposite.

Comment: On my current Thinkpad the license key sticker is inside the battery case - so that it doesn't wear off.